# Ideas for reducing data loaded into spark for a join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, spark-streaming

So I have an input data stream that is logs of file activity. I need to join this data with a table that contains metadata on each fileId.

The job runs hourly. There are about 1M logs per hour, and about 5B total files (or 5B total rows in the file-metadata table). This means even in the worst case scenario (where every log refers to a unique file) we'd only see 1M fileIds and so would only need about 1/5000 of the file-metadata rows. The problem is that we still have to load all 5B rows into memory, and the size of the file-metadata table is about 500GB and takes 10-15 minutes of each run just to load.

1/5000 is pretty inefficient and this load time is killing our job performance and cogs. It feels like there should be a way to load less of the data, or not have to load it every time, or some other idea. Reducing this by 5x to just 1/1000 seems like a reasonable ask, but I have no idea how to get there.

I'm sure this is a very common issue in the big data world so I was just wondering what strategies exist for this problem. Any resources around this would be appreciated as well.

Ideas I've had:

- I've thought about sharding the table into smaller chunks and somehow grouping by priority, but there's a perf tradeoff with loading more files, plus even if I sharded it into 5K files, each file would have 1M rows and the odds of NONE of those fileIds being present in the incoming log stream seems very low.
- I've thought of keeping the table in memory and having longer running jobs, but keeping 500GB of memory dedicated like this is a big resource ask.
- I've thought about doing larger batches (running the job in 6-hour batches instead of hourly), however 1M rows already involves some heavy compute and increasing that to 6M might not be a good idea. Also we want to move towards a streaming job anyway.
- We have other jobs that use this data, so I can imagine a solution where this table is permanently loaded in some shared memory and all jobs can read from this place. The problem is we have to distribute it onto the executors to do our join, which leads right back to the original problem. Perhaps you could use a bloom filter to only load a subset of the data from shared memory into the executors.

Final thoughts:

- We want to move from running this as an hourly batch job towards a streaming job, so the solution would ideally work there as well.
- We already employ a bloom filter, but this still requires loading ALL of the data into memory and then filtering it down from there. Also, once we move to a streaming job I'm not sure we can even use a bloom filter anymore.

Comment: Did you consider bucketing?

Answer (score 0):

If your big file-metadata table is a parquet file, it automatically comes with predicate pushdown. See [this page](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cdh_ig_predicate_pushdown_parquet.html) for a bit more info about this subject. The configuration is called `spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown` and is [true by default](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#configuration) in recent Spark versions. You'll just need to add sensible filters to the `spark.read.parquet` call.

You can indeed go the full streaming route and then working with a [delta lake](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html) might even give you a simpler solution.

Hope this helps!